# Random spanning trees probability problem

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, graph-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walks

We are given a simple connected graph $G(V,E)$ with vertex and edge set $V$ and $E$ respectively. For any vertex $v\in V$, let $D_T(v)$ the degree of $v$ in a uniformly generated random spanning tree $T$ of $G$.

---

**Question:** I am interested in bounding the maximum variance of the $D_T(v)$ over all vertices $v\in V$. I tried to find results published on this topic, but unfortunately, I could not find anything. Are you aware of some known results about it?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, for fixed $v$ the variance of $D_T(v)$ does not exceed $\frac14\deg(v)$, where $\deg$ is the degree of $v$ in $G$. Does this make you happy?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking $o(\mathrm{deg}(v))$ for $\mathrm{deg}(v)\to\infty$. Thank you. Where can I find (or prove) such result?

Comment: But it is not $o(\deg v)$. Or you mean $o((\deg v)^2)$?

Comment: Now I know @FedorPetrov that it is not $o(\mathrm{deg}(v)$ . I meant that previously I thought (without any proof) that the maximum variance could not be as large as a constant fraction of the degree for huge graphs. I am a bit surprised.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I asked this question because I wanted to use this result for bounding $R_v$ in the problem https://mathoverflow.net/q/443550/115803

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a proof that the variance of $d_T(v)$ does not exceed $\frac14(\deg v-1)$.

For every edge $e\in E$ take a variable $x_e$ and consider the polynomial $$P:=\sum_T \prod_{e\in T} x_e,$$
where the sum is taken over all spanning trees $T$ of $G$. It is known (see Proposition 1.1 [here](https://people.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/mckenzie/mckenzie.pdf), for example) that $P$ is stable: it does not vanish if all variables take values in the open upper half-plane. Real stable (that means, stable and with real coefficients) polynomials enjoy some nice properties, including the following: if you replace some variables to the real constants, you get a real stable polynomial again (or identical zero), see Theorem 2.4, p. b) [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.16847.pdf). If you assign the value 1 for each $x_e$ where $e$ is not incident to $v$ and the value $t$ (new variable) for each $x_e$ where $e$ is incident to $v$, you, so, get a univariate real stable polynomial $h(t)=\sum_{T} t^{d_T(v)}$. We have $h(0)=0$, and, since $h$ is real stable, all other roots of $h$ are non-positive real numbers: $h(t)=t(t+\alpha_1)\ldots(t+\alpha_k)$, where $k\leqslant \deg v-1$ (well, if the graph $G$ does not have multiple edges incident to $v$, than $k=\deg v-1$). On probabilistic language, it means that the distribution of $d_T(v)-1$ is a convolution of $k$ Bernoulli distributions with parameters $1/(\alpha_i+1)$. Thus the variance of $d_T(v)-1$ equals $$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{\alpha_i}{(1+\alpha_i)^2}\leqslant \frac14 k\leqslant \frac14(\deg v-1).$$
I have seen somewhere the fact that distribution of (degree minus 1) in a random spanning tree is a convolution of Bernoullis (with above proof), but it is more difficult to remember where, than to reproduce the proof.

Note also that for fixed $n=\deg v$ the bound $(n-1)/4$ for the variance is tight, and is attained, for example (or only?) at $K_{2,n}$.

Comment: If I calculate correctly, for $k$ triangles sharing a vertex, the variance at the common vertex is $2k/9$ compared to the degree $2k$. So your bound is high by less than a factor of $9/4$ and we can ask where the best bound is.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay for $K_{2,n}$ the bound $(n-1)/4$ seems to be tight.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Very nice.

Comment: Thank you, beautiful proof.

Answer (score 4):

The connection between uniform spanning trees $T$ and stable polynomials used in Fedor Petrov's answer is indeed beautiful, and yields a sharp bound. I want to mention that the slightly weaker bound of deg$(v)/4$  follows from two classical 19th century results :  For any two distinct edges $e,f$ in the graph $G$, the events $e \in T$ and $f \in T$ are negatively correlated by Kirchoff's theorem relating spanning trees to electrical resistance, and the Rayleigh monotonicity principle. See Corollary 4.3(b) in [1] or Exercise 4.3 (page 107) in [2].

Denote by $I_e$ the indicator of $e \in T$ and let $E_v$ be the set of edges in $G$ incident to $v$. Then
$$\text{Var}(\text{deg}(v))=\sum_{e,f \in E_v} \text{Cov}(I_e,I_f) \le  \sum_{e  \in E_v} \text{Var}(I_e) \le \text{deg}(v)/4.
$$

[1] https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-29/issue-1/Uniform-spanning-forests/10.1214/aop/1008956321.full

[2] https://rdlyons.pages.iu.edu/prbtree/book_pb.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the answer, a simple yet very interesting bound.

Comment: For what it worth, this negative correlation also follows from real stability (if the polynomial $Axy+Bx+Cx+D$ with non-negative coefficients is real stable, than $AD\leqslant BC$, equivalently $(A+B)(A+C)\geqslant A(A+B+C+D)$, which means corresponding non-positive correlation.)

Comment: Of course it does, real stability is a stronger property.